# Trying to write an Encryption algorithm

Tags: c, cs50

I am trying to create an algorithm that encrypt a message into another using a substitution method.

The user will run

```
./encryption.c KEY
```

where KEY is a string of letters that holds every letter of the alphabet only once. E.g.

```
./encryption.c bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza
```

It will then ask the user for a message they want to encrypt via this KEY. E.g. Hello World. The encryption will then follow a substitution-style algorithm.

This is where the program will look the first/next letter of the message, locate its place in the alphabet and substitute it in the encryption with the letter that holds that same place in the key (which should be a different letter).

It goes like this: (Where plaintext is the message, ciphertext is the encrypted text, and Alphabet is a array of the letters of the alphabet):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

const char Alphabet[26] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'}; // A collection of letters to teach the computer the alphabet.
string plaintext = get_string("plaintext: ");
char ciphertext[strlen(plaintext) + 1];
ciphertext[strlen(plaintext) + 1] = '\0';
for (int j = 0; j < strlen(plaintext); j ++) // Handling the first/next letter of plaintext.
{
    char letter = plaintext[j];
    bool needCapital = isupper(letter);
    char cipherletter;
    for (int k = 0; k < strlen(ciphertext); k ++) // Finding the position of said letter.
    {
        char compe = Alphabet[k];
        if (needCapital == true)
        {
            compe = toupper(Alphabet[k]);
        }
        if (compe == letter)
        {
            cipherletter = key[k]; // Encryption.
            ciphertext[j] = cipherletter;
            printf("%s\n", ciphertext);
            break;
        }
        else if (isalpha(compe) == false)// This path is used for keeping punctuation the same.
        {
            cipherletter = letter;
            ciphertext[j] = cipherletter;
            printf("%s\n", ciphertext);
        }
    }
}
printf("ciphertext: %s\n", ciphertext); // End---
```

(Apologies for the long length of code) `int main(void)` would go around all of this.

However, while my code compiles properly, the program seems to be confused somewhere as it does not encrypt the message correctly at all...
Could anyone please try and run this and tell me where I have gone wrong? I hope I have managed to explain it properly but feel free to ask me to explain anything further.

Comment: Please feel free to run the program with a key and message and see what the program does. Thanks.

Comment: `string`? What's this in a C program?

EDIT: Oh, this is CS50. Ugh. Please add all the #includes required to compile this.

Comment: `ciphertext[strlen(plaintext) + 1] = '\0';` is outside the bounds: please use `ciphertext[strlen(plaintext)] = '\0';`

Comment: Line 4 has an out of bounds access,

Comment: I don't see where `key` is initialized.

Comment: `for (int k = 0; k < strlen(ciphertext); k ++)` -- the upper bound for this loop should be `sizeof(Alphabet)`

Comment: and @WeatherVane

Comment: Im still getting an incorrect encryption, is there something wrong with my algorithm

Comment: Thanks @SteveFriedl, all #includes have been added